# Splitting a string truncates the word in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I try to setup a custom button with `UIImage` and `UILabel`

After setting up constraints, I started testing this button and noticed strange behavior

`UILabel` in `UIButton` code:

```
private var title: UILabel = {
    var label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5

    return label
}()
```

When I set title for example `"Hfpdktxtybz"`, `UILabel` works amazing!

One word takes one line:

[image: 1]

But if I try set title for example `"Развлечения"`, `UILabel` truncates the word.

One word is split into two lines:

[image: 2]

Why for English language label work is correctly, but for Russian language truncates the word? How to fix it?
The number of characters is the same

Comment: If you want 1 line consider changing the `label.numberOfLines = 0`.
Maybe for some reason the Russian word you added has bigger width hence the 2 lines.
I guess the width has to do with the font as well.
Also take a look at this one https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13148/which-fonts-have-the-same-width-for-every-character

Comment: I don't see any truncation in your example. Perhaps you mean something else?

Comment: I think I know you! Are you associated with Supercell?

Comment: @BigBrother Quite possibly :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, as said in the comments, that characters don't necessarily have the same width.

- lllll
- AAAAA
- aaaaa

The above example clearly shows characters do not have the same width although they have same character count.
So Autolayout calculates the UILabel real width and it has only one option in order to satisfy your constraints. That is to split it into 2 lines.

If you don't want this to happen consider changing UILabel priority `numberOfLines`.

Comment: Changing `numberOfLines = 3` This solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### if you use storyboard

[image]

#### if you use swift programmatically.

```
label.numberOfLines = 2
```